# Enable USB debugging (under settings/applications/development) programmatically from within an app

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

Is it possible to enable USB debugging (under settings/applications/development) programmatically from within my app?

I was looking at `Permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` and
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html, 
but I couldn't find anything appropriate.

Comment: simple curiosity : Why would you like to do that in an app as you need a driver when you connect to a computer?

Comment: that's not a problem. i'm writing a sync app (java webstart) that will be running on a pre-defined set of computers. users shall be able to sync the phone, but when I hand out the devices to them, it's in non-debug mode. When the users wants to sync, the app shall enable/disable the debug mode, as they user will never exit my app. 
My app starts on bootup and is set at the default home intent by default. (background: I'm bundling the app with a device, which I then rent out to the user). But the 'sync stations' will be pre-configured and have JRE, Device drivers, etc. already installed.

Comment: ... plus I want to call adb from the sync program... which is why simple usb mounting is not enough (or would require additional workarounds)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You will need root permissions to do so from an app.**

That said, it *is* possible to enable ADB by executing the following terminal commands:

```
setprop persist.service.adb.enable 1
start adbd
```

[This blog post](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html) gives an excellent example of how to execute these commands with escalated permissions through `su`.

Comment: I changed and marked this answer as correct solution in favor over my own answer I gave two years earlier. Maybe things changed over time, but even this answer is also 7 years old. I haven't tested it myself, but given the upvotes, I assume it's correct.

Answer (score 9):

First: **Your app must be a system app**

This line of code may help:

`Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Global.ADB_ENABLED, 1);`

and you need this permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>`

but after adding this permission in manifest you will get this error:
**Permission is only granted to system apps**

which means **your app must be a system app**.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible without using your own custom firmware that grants access to the security settings.
See thread here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/953c6f0eb0fa9bed#

Answer (score 5):

You can enable adb programmatically by requesting WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS in manifest and granting it over adb shell:

```
adb shell pm grant your.package.name android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Then you can enable adb on API 17 and above by calling:

```
Settings.Global.putString(mContext.getContentResolver, Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED,"1");
```

For API 16 to API 3 call:

```
Settings.Secure.putString(mContext.getContentResolver, Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED,"1");
```

To disable adb replace "1" with "0" in commands

Comment: Thanks for the hint, good to know. Good if I had that flag 8 year ago.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these 3 steps

1. in the manifest put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>`
2. Use this command in the code to enable USB debug `Settings.Secure.putInt(requireActivity().contentResolver, Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 1)` or `Settings.Secure.putInt(requireActivity().contentResolver, Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0)` to disable it
3. **IMPORTANT** Before being able to use these system API you must grant WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS from adb running `adb shell pm grant your.package.name android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`. The device has to be attached to the computer with USB debug active.

I developed a simple app that uses this approach to enable/disable some developer options such as *Debug USB* and *Keep Device Screen Active* https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.stzan.devtools

**Disclaimer: I am the actual developer of DevTools**

Answer (score 0):

If your device has root, and API level > 17 for enable adb:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "settings put global adb_enabled 1"});
```

or (depends of su implementation)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "settings put global adb_enabled 1"});
```

For disable - change last argument from 1 to 0