# Android - Programmatically check developer options?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a application thats uses intent to make photos with camera, but lately i have met a problem for users using developer options like 'Background process limit' that they turn off all background apps - so my app is killed besides calling onPause and onResume. I'd wish if theres any possibility to check if this options is turn off and so I could prompt user a proper dialog.

Comment: check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985251/how-to-access-device-settings-programmatically

Comment: its seems that only system settings can be checked, so there's no way for checking developer settings?

Comment: The system may choose to kill your app whether or not the option is set.  I take it you're holding the camera and taking pictures of things while your app is in the background?

Comment: @fadden exactly like You say...

Answer (score 37):

You can open with

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```