# how to enable developer option automatically in android mobile

Tags: android

Is it possible to enable the developer option in Android mobile automatically?

i wanted to enable the developer option without user intervention for achieving some requirement.

Can we able to enable it through any android API or by developing and installing app in the mobile?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985251/how-to-access-device-settings-programmatically). But you need root access.

Answer (score 0):

1:You always need for the first time to enable developer option manually from your mobile setting Tab by clicking 7 times to the Build number.

2:After enabling developers option you need to click the always remember menu into your mobile for future use.

Answer (score 0):

No It is not possible 
You have to do it manually from your android setting option and then from developer option