# Is it possible to check if "Show layout bounds" setting is enabled?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-11, android-settings

How can I detect whether the user set "Show layout bounds" as enabled from Developer Options of Settings programmatically?

I couldn't find any constant like `Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED` that relevant to layout bounds to get settings as the following

```
Settings.Secure.getInt(applicationContext.contentResolver,
                Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 0)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access device settings programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985251/how-to-access-device-settings-programmatically)

Comment: @HenryTwist Would be used as a cheat for the game in my mind

Comment: @javdromero Thanks but  I couldn't find any constant like ``Settings.Secure.LAYOUT_BOUNDS_BLA_BLA`` or ``Settings.System.LAYOUT_BOUNDS_BLA_BLA``  in the solution you sent

Answer (score 1):

Since API level 30 the `View` class has a method [isShowingLayoutBounds()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#isShowingLayoutBounds()) that returns `true` when the View is attached and the system developer setting to show the layout bounds is enabled.

Note, that the view must be attached to the hierarchy in order to return a correct value. Plus, you may want to check the value in `onResume`, since the user might change the setting while the app is running.

Example:

```kotlin
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val showLayoutBoundsEnabled = window.decorView.isShowingLayoutBounds
}
```